# Prove that $A \triangle B = A \setminus B \iff B \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I think I've proved this, but am unsure if it is correct. (I'm self-studying through a "transitions" book). Here, the $\triangle$ is the *symmetric difference*.

---

*Lemma*: For two sets $A$ and $B$, if $B \setminus A = \emptyset$ then $B \subseteq A$.

*Proof*: Let $x \in B$. Since, by the antecedent, $B \setminus A = \emptyset$, we know that it is not the case that $x \notin A$, so we must have $x \in A$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary element of $B$, we can conclude that $B \subseteq A$.

---

*Theorem*: For sets $A$ and $B$, $A \triangle B = A \setminus B \iff B \subseteq A$

*Proof*:

- ($\rightarrow$) By definition, $A \triangle B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$. By the antecedent, then, $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (A \setminus B)$. We showed earlier (in the book) that for two sets $X, Y$: $X \cup Y = X \iff Y \subseteq X$, so this means $B \setminus A \subseteq A \setminus B$. However, let $x \in B \setminus A$, which implies $x \in A \setminus B$. This cannot happen because an element cannot be in both $A$ and $A^C$, so we conclude that $B \setminus A = \emptyset$. By the Lemma above, then $B \subseteq A$.
- ($\leftarrow$) Since $B \subseteq A$, we know that $A \cup B = A$ and $A \cap B = B$. By the definition of symmetric difference, $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = A \setminus B$.

Comment: Looks good. One note, though: you say that "by definition", $A \triangle B$ equals both $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ and $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$. Were you given both of these definitions, or were you given one of them and had to prove that the other was equivalent?

Comment: @ConnorHarris the book gave the first, and in another exercise I proved that the second was equivalent.

Comment: One final small note on proof-writing: when you assign a name to an arbitrary element, it sometimes helps to be explicit that this is what you're doing: "Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $B$" or "Take $x \in B$ arbitrary" rather than just "Let $x \in B$." Your writing is still very clear, but this is a good habit to get into because there are times when it may not be obvious whether you meant to give a *particular* element a name or just use a variable name as a generic placeholder.